# Unexpected plugin_dir_path Output

Tags: plugins, functions, paths

I am developing locally and have a problem with this code:

```
plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'ben/'
```

If I echo this out it is: **C:\xampp\htdocs\plugintest\wp-content\plugins\my-plugin\admin/ben/**

If I try to use it in a function:

```
function my_acf_settings_path( $path ) {
    $path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'ben/';
    return $path;
}
```

The output is: **http://localhost/plugintestC:xampphtdocsplugintestwp-contentpluginsmy-pluginadmin/ben/**

Why?

Comment: the result is unlikely to be related to the line of code you use, show the full relevant code

Comment: I am actually attempting to use the code here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/including-acf-in-a-plugin-theme/ but changing the template directory to my plugin directory, the include seems to work but the other 2 functions seems to use the URL menttionned.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by using plugin_dir_url.

Comment: Can you please put the code here ?